# Is is possible to detect Undo/Redo in a Powerpoint Addin via C#?

Tags: c#, add-in, powerpoint, undo, undo-redo

Is is possible to detect Undo/Redo events in a Powerpoint Addin via C#? Or is it possible to access what has happened or manipulate the Undo/Redo list?

I ask because I haven't seen anything that allows this, which makes me surprised, I was expecting it to be possible, so I'm asking mostly in the hope that I've missed something.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PPT doesn't expose the undo list, unfortunately, and there's no event you can trap to let you know when an undo/redo has taken place.

I suppose it'd be possible to implement your own undo stack but that seems like the kind of thing Stephen King would write novels about. ;-)

Comment: Sigh, and here I was hoping that wasn't the case... Thanks for the info @Steve...

Comment: Now that the new web-based addins have an even more ridiculously limited API it's time to discourage anyone ever trying to build a PPT addin.

Comment: @SoonDead  Why?  VBA still works, COM still works.  Just because MS introduced a new and nearly useless API doesn't mean anyone needs to use it when there are better, proven technologies available.

Comment: Yes it's true. My point was that the API for VSTO is very-very quirky and has useful features missing (like getting thumbnails of slides, find out if a slide has been changed, or even consistently find which slide the user actually sees). And instead of reworking these into a more pleasant API experience, MS releases a ridiculous JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for an event for Ctrl+Z/Undo. The idMso control for the Undo feature is a gallery so that's a dead end in terms of repurposing via a  in the customUI. There's no built in Application.OnUndo event and the only other thing I can think of is using WinAPIs to hook into the WindowProc procedure for PowerPoint to detect Ctrl+Z. I tried it briefly and can detect that key combination but I despise the instability this kind of thing causes, causing PowerPoint to potentially crash on some systems, and it doesn't address macOS. Here's the basis of the technique should someone want to refine it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal ID As Long, ByVal fsModifiers As Long, ByVal vk As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal ID As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" ( _
                                        ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, _
                                        ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                        ByVal MSG As Long, _
                                        ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
                                        ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public hWndPPT As LongPtr

Public Type POINTAPI
  x As Long
  y As Long
End Type

Public Type MSG
    hwnd As LongPtr
    Message As Long
    wParam As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    time As Long
    PT As POINTAPI
End Type

#If Win64 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#End If

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Long = -4& ' Sets a new address for the window procedure

Private PrevWndFunc As LongPtr          ' Pointer to the initial window proc

Private Const WM_HOTKEY = &H312&        ' HotKey message

Private Const MOD_Control = 2           ' Either CTRL key

Public Sub RegisterCtrlZ()
    
    Dim returnedVal
    
    hWndPPT = GetPPThWnd
    
    returnedVal = RegisterHotKey(hwnd:=hWndPPT, ID:=1, fsModifiers:=MOD_Control, vk:=vbKeyZ)
    Debug.Print "RegisterHotKey returned " & returnedVal

    ' Set the window callback procedure
    PrevWndFunc = SetWindowLongPtr(hWndPPT, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)

End Sub

Public Sub UnregisterCtrlZ()
    
    Dim returnedVal

    hWndPPT = GetPPThWnd
    
    returnedVal = UnregisterHotKey(hwnd:=hWndPPT, ID:=1)
    Debug.Print "UnregisterHotKey returned " & returnedVal
    
    PrevWndFunc = SetWindowLongPtr(hWndPPT, GWL_WNDPROC, PrevWndFunc)
    
End Sub

Public Function WindowProc(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

    ' Check if a hotkey and the main PPT window is the active window
    If uMsg = WM_HOTKEY And GetActiveWindow = hWndPPT Then
        Debug.Print "Hotkey " & wParam & " event (Ctrl+Z)"
    End If
    
    ' Call the next window proc
    WindowProc = CallWindowProc(PrevWndFunc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
    
End Function

' Get the handle for the PowerPoint window
Public Function GetPPThWnd() As LongPtr

    Select Case Val(Application.Version)
        Case 8
            GetPPThWnd = FindWindow("PP97FrameClass", 0&)
        Case 9 To 12
            GetPPThWnd = FindWindow("PP" & Val(Application.Version) & "FrameClass", 0&)
        Case Else
            GetPPThWnd = FindWindow("PPTFrameClass", vbNullString)
    End Select
    
End Function
```